# animation based on device orientation with CSS?

Tags: css, animation, mobile, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I've created a page that has content showing & hiding based on the device orientation, however I find that there's somewhat of a jump/lag when you rotate and the content shows/hide.

Is it possible to animate a smoother transition between lelements showing/hiding using just css?

Comment: this sounds like something jquery could easily fix, but have you looked into webkit transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the elements that animate in and out of view, you can use `transition-property: all;` and `transition-duration: 1s;` (or whatever duration you'd like) to fade in/slide in said elements.  Of course those CSS properties will need to be prefixed in some browsers.